# can't sort out multiple inheritance in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

The documentation says this:

```
Python supports a form of multiple inheritance as well. A class 
definition with multiple base classes looks like this:

class DerivedClassName(Base1, Base2, Base3):
    <statement-1>
    .
    .
    .
    <statement-N>
For most purposes, in the simplest cases, you can think of the search 
for attributes inherited from a parent class as depth-first, left-to-
right, not searching twice in the same class where there is an overlap 
in the hierarchy. Thus, if an attribute is not found in 
DerivedClassName, it is searched for in Base1, then (recursively) in 
the base classes of Base1, and if it was not found there, it was 
searched for in Base2, and so on.
```

So, I have this code to test it:

```
class Class1:
        c1_1 = 1.1

class Class2:
        c2_1 = 2.1


class Blob(Class1, Class2):

    def dump():
        print('c1_1 = ' + str(c1_1))

Blob.dump()
```

But, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classinherit.py", line 13, in <module>
    Blob.dump()
  File "classinherit.py", line 11, in dump
    print('c_1.1 = ' + str(c1_1))
NameError: name 'c1_1' is not defined
```

The documentation seems to say Python will first look for a (in this case class-wide) variable in scope of class Blob, and not finding it will search classes Class1 and Class2...but that clearly is not happening.

What gives?

Comment: This has nothing to do with multiple inheritance, you are trying to access a variable that isn't defined. `c1_1`. You meant `self. c1_1`

Comment: Python will only do a class-based look-up if you access an attribute. You never try to do that in `dump`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access class variables, you must reference the class somehow:

```
class Class1:
        c1_1 = 1.1

class Class2:
        c2_1 = 2.1

class Blob(Class1, Class2):

    @classmethod
    def dump(cls):
        print('c1_1 = ' + str(cls.c1_1))

Blob.dump()
```

---

To make things clear, you must reference the class **always**, not just in case of inheritance.

E.g., the following will **not** work:

```
class Klass():
    v1 = 1

    def dump():
        print('class var = ' + str(v1))

Klass.dump()
```

> NameError: name 'v1' is not defined

Again, you will have to reference the class to make it work:

```
class Klass():
    v1 = 1

    @classmethod
    def dump(cls):
        print('class var = ' + str(cls.v1))

Klass.dump()
```

---

If you do not want to use `@classmethod`, you could also do the following:

```
class Klass():
    v1 = 1

    def dump():
        print('class var = ' + str(Klass.v1))

Klass.dump()
```

But keep in mind, that changing the name of the class `Klass` will also require a change of `Klass.v1`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what the docs say.  And, if that is the case, why even support multiple inheritance?  If I declare 'class Blob():...' I could just as easily say "print( 'c1_1= ' + str(Class1.c1_1))" .  What good does multiple inheritance do, and why do the docs seem to say otherwise?

Comment: Then what good does class inheritance do?  I could do the same be declaring 'class Blob():' and then printing 'str(Class1.c1_1)'.  The @classmethod seems a clumsy way to get nowhere with a lot more confusion.  And, it doesn't sqaure with the docs.

Comment: Your problem is with accessing a class variable, see my updated answer.

Comment: Bringing up classmethods here is confusing. You could just as easily use a *normal* method with `self`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but OP did not create a class instance in his question, thus I did not use an instance method. Actually, creating an instance if you're only accessing class attributes instead of instance attributes might be more confusing and lead to wrong expectations when it comes to changing the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is that you are trying to access the class variables and(or) attributes **without actually telling what class it belongs to or without referencing the class.** 
You can either see @Mike Scotty's answer or just properly call your class variables then you can clearly see how the MRO (Method Resolution Order) in Python works.

```
class A:
    a = 8

class B:
    b = 9

class C(A, B):
    c = 99
```

Output

```
d = C() #After instantiating
print(d.a, d.b, d.c)
>> 8 9 99
# Without instantiating
print(C.a, C.b, C.c)
>> 8 9 99
```

Comment: You don't need to make an instance to access attributes in parent classes. You can do `print(C.a, c.b, C.c)` if you want, without ever creating the instance `d`.

Comment: @Blckknght yes, you are correct, i missed that in a rush. Edited my answer, is it okay now?